# Selecting next quoted text in Vim

Tags: vim

I wanted to create a text object for the "next quoted text", for example in the code:

```
My cursor is HERE.
I want to delete 'what is inside here'
```

If the cursor is at the beginning of the word HERE, I would like to have something like `din'`, for delete inner *next* quotes. What is the correct sequence of keys to move to the next quoted text?

Observe that simply `/'<cr>` doesn't work properly. Consider:

```
'My cursor is HERE. But I do not want to delete this'
...
'But this!'
```

As the example suggests, if I press `din'` (and the cursor is at the beginning of HERE), I want to delete the *next* quoted text, that is 'But this!'.
For example, the following text object would delete 'My cursor is HERE. But I don't want to delete this':

```
vnoremap <silent> in' :<C-U> execute "normal! /)\rvi'"<CR>
onoremap <silent> in' :<C-U> execute "normal! /)\rvi'"<CR>
```

Comment: Is the apostrophe in the `don't` here on purpose? because it makes it kind of hard to distinguate the apostrophes being quotes and the apostrophes as part of English language

Comment: You could try to find the second next quote, then issue `di"`. If you are within a quote, you will jump to the beginning of the next, else you are at the end of the second quote. Both should yield the expected result.

Comment: @Zorzi you're right, I edited it and removed the single quote, thanks!

Comment: @Chelz it could work, but I'm just thinking to one edge case. Consider `'My cursor is HERE'. And there is no closing single quote'.`. Deleting inside the next second single quote in this case (with something like `din'`, using the text object `onoremap  in' :<c-u> execute "normal! /'\rnvi'"<cr>`) would delete the quote, while I expect nothing to happen. Anyway great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
2/'<CR>di'
```

Alternatively you can use the * command:

```
f'*di'
```

Comment: I think this solution has the same problem that I mentioned in one previous comment: it is not gonna work if there's no closing quote. Furthermore, the command `f` works only on the same line, while I want to be able to match quotes in multiple lines.